# How to use the default keycloak.json instead of spring properties

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, keycloak

I was following this example to set up keycloak with springboot

```
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
```

I have used the bellow bean so I can use spring boot properties file.
which all worked fine. 
But if I wanted to use the Keycloak.json file instead of spring boot properties, what I did was commented out the  KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver been and included the keycloak.json file in resources/WEB-INF/keycloak.json. but I keep getting the following error.
am I missing something? how do I use the keycloak.json file and where should this file go? or is there some configuration I missed? all the examples show using spring properties and not json file. Any ideas? or if you could point me to an example that uses the default keycloak.json

```
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setKeycloakSpringBootProperties' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}



   @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this to your configuration file:

   ```
   keycloak:
   configurationFile: "classpath:keycloak.json"
   ```
2. Put the `keycloak.json` directly into the resources directory.
3. Use only keycloak adapter as dependency:  `org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter`

Comment: for properties file(not a yaml):Reason: The elements [keycloak.configurationfile] were left unbound.